# Not able to Disable/Enable scheduled task in Win 7

Tags: visual-c++, windows-7, scheduled-tasks

I am using task scheduler 1.0 interface in my appln.

In my appln creating task at scheduled time and Disable/Enable task after successful creation by setting the flag IScheduledWorkItem::SetFlags(TASK_FLAG_DISABLED)

In Win 7 task creation is happening but not able to Disable/Enable scheduled task.

Same appln works fine in Win2003 and Win-XP.

does anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Task Scheduler was completely rewritten in Windows 6.0. You need to switch to the [`ITaskService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface instead for 7 / Server 2k8 R2.

Comment: Is this ITaskService interface supports all the platform of windows OR only for Win7 / Server 2k8 R2 ?

Answer (score 0):

I have hit this wall myself. See [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-PT/windowscompatibility/thread/e4ae41b6-4840-40ff-a18a-7edad1e72ef3) for some answers. Specifically, it seems that `VISTA: "...The Task Scheduler 2.0 API should be used in developing applications that use the Task Scheduler service on Windows Vista.."`

The only proper way is to go for Task 2 API.